# saving hebrew utf8 to database with php

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

when saving hebrew to a mysql database (utf-8) i am getting it converted to something like this:

```
&times;&uml;&times;
```

editing content directly in the database works and it outputs on the page fine too.

sorry forgot to ask a question... what am i doing wrong!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure inserting into the database will definitely *not* put entities into your input. The conversion *must* take place somewhere else.

You should step through the whole path the data takes, and see whether there's not a `htmlentities` executed somewhere.

Comment: +1 it does look exactly like an `htmlentities()` done without passing the charset in. Use `htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8')`, or, much simpler, just use `htmlspecialchars` instead, since that doesn't try to molest the non-ASCII characters. It's almost always the better function.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the `html_entity_decode` function on your data while saving it to your DB. Somewhere in your code there's probably a call to `htmlentities` that's responsible for your conversions.

BTW: please make sure calling `mysql_real_escape` on your data just BEFORE inserting it into your DB (without your vulnarable like ... hell).

Comment: The better answer is to fix whatever is calling `htmlentities` in the first place, rather than just encoding it to be unencoded.